# Passing variable for ggplot2 as a function argument - not mapping levels to fill aesthetic correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to refactor this code as a function, but it's not giving me the expected output. In the original code, the `color` levels are mapped to individual plots - the desired behavior. In the refactored code, I get a single plot with a single level `color`. There are no errors or anything, and I've used `browser()` inside the function call to confirm the levels using `unique()` and everything looks correct.  Not sure why this isn't working.

### Example Working Code:

```
#### Load and prep the data set####
data(diamonds)

### Create bins for carat ###
carat_bins <- seq(0, ceiling(max(diamonds$carat) * 2) / 2, by = 0.5)  

### Add the bins to the table ###
diamonds$carat_bin <- cut(diamonds$carat, breaks = carat_bins, include.lowest = TRUE)

#### Plot ####
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat_bin, y = price, fill = color)) +
  geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.15) +
  labs(x = "Carat", y = "Price", fill = "Color") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Diamond Prices by Carat and Color") +
  theme_minimal()
```

### Example Refactored Code (function replaces `Plot` section above):

```
#### Plot Function ####
my_plot <- function(x_var, fill_var) {
  
  ### Ensure fill_var is factored ###
  diamonds[[fill_var]] <- factor(diamonds[[fill_var]])
  
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x_var, y = price, fill = fill_var)) +
    geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.15)
}

#### Test ####
my_plot("carat_bin", "color")
```

### Output from working code:

[image: plot correctly factored by color level]

### Output from refactored code:

[image: plot incorrectly ignoring color levels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `!!ensym()` (so that `ggplot` evaluates the strings as variables):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(diamonds)

### Create bins for carat ###
carat_bins <- seq(0, ceiling(max(diamonds$carat) * 2) / 2, by = 0.5)  

### Add the bins to the table ###
diamonds$carat_bin <- cut(diamonds$carat, breaks = carat_bins, include.lowest = TRUE)


#### Plot Function ####
my_plot <- function(x_var, fill_var) {
  
  ### Ensure fill_var is factored ###
  diamonds[[fill_var]] <- factor(diamonds[[fill_var]])
  
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = !!ensym(x_var), y = price, fill = !!ensym(fill_var))) +
    geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.15)
}

#### Test ####
my_plot("carat_bin", "color")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So while the `!!ensym()` method worked within a regular `R` session, it created an error when I tried to use it in a code chunk within a markdown document. I wanted to post this answer to share a simple solution I found that also plays nicely in markdown.

```
data(diamonds)

### Create bins for carat ###
carat_bins <- seq(0, ceiling(max(diamonds$carat) * 2) / 2, by = 0.5)  

### Add the bins to the table ###
diamonds$carat_bin <- cut(diamonds$carat, breaks = carat_bins, include.lowest = TRUE)


#### Plot Function ####
my_plot <- function(x_var, fill_var) {
  
  ### Ensure fill_var is factored ###
  diamonds[[fill_var]] <- factor(diamonds[[fill_var]])
  
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = .data[[x_var]], y = price, fill = .data[[fill_var]])) +
    geom_violin(position = "identity", alpha = 0.15)
}

#### Test ####
my_plot("carat_bin", "color")
```